# Jooq save or update method returns an error

Tags: java, jooq

i'm trying to implement save or update method using jooq and table with unique constraint "phone_number_key"
My code:

```java
var insertStep = dslContext.insertInto(Users.USERS)
        .set(Users.USERS.FIRSTNAME, user.getFirstname())
        .set(Users.USERS.PHONENUMBER, user.getPhoneNumber())
        .onConflict()
        .doUpdate()
        .set(Users.USERS.FIRSTNAME, user.getFirstname())
        .returningResult(Users.USERS.ID);
var record = insertStep.fetchOne();
```

but i got exception

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
> "phone_number_key"   Detail: Key ("phoneNumber")=(+999999999) already exists.

I got same error with ".onDuplicateKeyUpdate()" method
I use postgres db
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you post the table definition (`CREATE TABLE ...`)

Answer (score 2):

got it work with

```java
.onConflict(Users.USERS.PHONENUMBER)
.doUpdate()
.set(Users.USERS.FIRSTNAME, user.getFirstname())
```